# About sending time to infinity in a slightly imaginary direction in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am going through the Peskin and Schroeder QFT book. While proving the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem) in chapter 4 of their book, the authors started with the equation
\begin{equation}
e^{-iHt}|0\rangle = e^{-iE_{0}t}| \Omega\rangle \langle \Omega | 0 \rangle + \sum_{n\ne0}e^{-iE_{n}t}| n\rangle \langle n | 0 \rangle
\end{equation}
And argued that for all the $n\ne0$ terms die out in the limit time $t$ send to $\infty$ in a **slightly imaginary direction**: $t \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)$. Which yields equation (4.27) namely

\begin{equation}
| \Omega \rangle = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)}\frac{e^{-iHt}|0\rangle}{e^{-iE_{0}t}\langle \Omega | 0 \rangle}\tag{4.27}
\end{equation}
I am confused about sending the time $t$ to $\infty$ in a **slightly imaginary direction**: $t \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)$. Is this something mathematically rigorous or just a purely mathematical artifact? I hope someone can enlighten me making this point clear.

Comment: I think we'd need a bit of an explanation about what all those symbols represent

Comment: @David, All I interested in to know what happens when  time t to ∞ in a slightly imaginary direction:

Comment: "slightly imaginary" is itself a slightly hard term to define. Are we working with some kind of "surreal" extension of the complex plane that allows for infinitesimals? In principle there's nothing wrong with the "algebra", but I'm not sure if the result is meaningful